# How is this inequality justified? Steps given.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

I am told to prove $$\left|\frac{a+b}{1+\overline{a}b}\right|<1 \quad\text{ when $|a|<1, b <1 $}$$ now ensues the finished assignment as in a notebook, I will highlight what is unclear to me:
Therefore:
$$\iff|a+b|<|1+\overline{a}b|^2$$ then what I believe I am reading is squaring these sides, but I just don't understand how, and would love if someone could help put why this is:

$$\iff|a|^2+a\overline{b}+b\overline{a}+|b|^2<1+\overline{a}b+\overline{b}a+|a|^2|b|^2.$$ the assignment goes on to a couple of more steps which as very trivial.

Comment: Did you forget to square $|a+b|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|z|^2=z\bar z$.

So, in your case, we have
$$|a+b|^2=(a+b)(\overline{a+b})=(a+b)(\overline a+\overline b)$$ and
$$|1+\overline ab|^2=(1+\overline ab)(\overline{1+\overline ab})=(1+\overline ab)(1+a\overline b).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $|a+b|^2 = (a+b)\overline{(a+b)}=(\overline{a}+\overline{b})$ and $|1+\overline{a}b|^2=(1+\overline{a}b)\overline{(1+\overline{a}b)} =(1+\overline{a}b)(1+a\overline{b})$.

Another way of proving this is by first showing that, for any $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$,

$$|1+\overline{a}b|^2-|a+b|^2=(1-|a|^2)(1-|b|^2)$$

If $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$, your result follows.